# Searching XML Elements by Attributes (C#)

Tags: c#, xml

I'm Trying to check XML elements for specific attributes so I can keep from saving duplicate element entries. the XML looks more or less like this:

```
    <root>
      <artist name="Coldplay">
        <track name="yellow" artist="Coldplay" url="coldplay.com/yellow" playCount="123" />
        <track name="fix you" artist="Coldplay" url="coldplay.com/fixyou" playCount="135" >
      </artist>
      //ect.
    </root>
```

google and various search results suggest something like

```
[@id='foo']
```

but i don't know what *that* is and for reasons that might be more obvious to you than to me i can't "google" a collection of special characters like that without getting bizarre results. So If anyone can offer a suggestion for an if checking statement I'd be much obliged! or a name or link for how special characters are used in C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an [XPath expression](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) - but personally, I'd use LINQ to XML for the searching myself:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");

var track = doc.Descendants("track")
               .Where(t => (string) t.Attribute("id") == "foo")
               .FirstOrDefault();
```

(Use `Single`, `SingleOrDefault`, `First` etc if you want to.)

Answer (score 2):

It's an XPath expression. You can use them along with a variety of XML-related objects in c#.

```
XmlDocument xd = new XmlDocument();
xd.LoadXml( xmlString );

XmlNodeList nodes = xd.SelectNodes( "//root/artist/track[@name='yellow']" );
```

General Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086.aspx

XPath with LINQ: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675183.aspx.